# Multiple data objects by extension using a protocol

Tags: ios, objective-c, protocols, uitouch

I had the great idea to use a a protocol on the UITouch class to extend it with some methods declared in the protocol. The reason of such a construct is to provide the protocol inside a framework to other users that they can send UITouch-similar data objects (Because they can't create a native UITouch object).

The protocol (myProtocol.h) is quite easy:

```
//  myProtocol.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol myProtocol <NSObject>

- (CGFloat) MYPREFIX_radius;

@end
```

Now i have a simple extension on UITouch using that protocol

```
//  UITouch+MYPREFIX_Extension.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "myProtocol.h"

@interface UITouch (MYPREFIX_Extension) <myProtocol>

@end
```

and

```
//  UITouch+MYPREFIX_Extension.m

#import "UITouch+MYPREFIX_Extension.h"

@implementation UITouch (MYPREFIX_Extension)

- (CGFloat) MYPREFIX_radius  {
    return self.majorRadius;
}

@end
```

By this everything is good to me. Now I built a touchRecognizer.

```
//  touchRecognizer.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface touchRecognizer : UITouch

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;

@end
```

In the touchRecognizer.m the problem begins. There I cast the UITouch object to a NSObject by using the protocol.And then I simply want to get access to the newly defined method MYPREFIX_radius and it should give me back the UITouch.major_radius.

```
//   touchRecognizer.m

#import "touchRecognizer.h"
#import "UITouch+MYPREFIX_Extension.h"

@interface touchRecognizer()

@end

@implementation touchRecognizer

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event     {
    for(NSObject<myProtocol> *touch in touches)   {
        NSLog(@"radius %f", touch.MYPREFIX_radius);
    }
}

@end
```

But when I run the code it just gives me the Error

> -[UITouch MYPREFIX_radius]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1701887b0

I don't understand it. What do I miss?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You want a category, not a protocol - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html

Comment: @Paulw11 He has a category.

Comment: 1. Why do you cast to `NSObject<protocol>`? 2. Are you sure that the bundle containing the category is already loaded?

Comment: The idea of the cast is to provide the same behaviour to UITouch and to MYPREFIX_Extension objects. Since the MYPREFIX_Entension is basically a superclass (every UITouch method plus my extras) it could work like that?

Comment: it will not work as you can't extend a foundation class like nsstring,nsarray etc. you have to change uitouch extension to uitouch category then it will work for you

Comment: So it won't work with an extension (which is almost a category), but with a real category? Now I am confused :/

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you forget to add the implementation file (`UITouch+MYPREFIX_Extension.m`) to your build target

Comment: I added it and still the same :-( . The framework itself is included as working project inside the big project. Xcode itself even does the autocomplete on this thing. It compiles and starts without any problem, but when there comes a touch, then i get the error i described before.

Comment: @copydigital: The autocomplete and stuff are compile-time. It not working when you touch it is runtime. They are completely separate. Code that calls this method will compile fine as long as they include a header that declares it. But that does not mean the method is actually implemented.

Comment: @copydigital: Try adding the `-ObjC` linker flag to your build settings. If that doesn't work, you can also try `-all_load` (shouldn't be necessary). Linking of Objective-C categories is not straightforward.